# when more cores used Spark (Sparklyr) error to many files open

Tags: azure, apache-spark, sparklyr

I am using the following configuration on Sparklyr in local mode:

```
conf <- spark_config()
conf$`sparklyr.cores.local` <- 28
conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "1000G"
conf$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.9

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local", 
                version = "2.1.1",
                config = conf)
```

This works fine when I read in a csv using spark_read_csv. However when I used more cores such as

```
conf <- spark_config()
conf$`sparklyr.cores.local` <- 30
conf$`sparklyr.shell.driver-memory` <- "1000G"
conf$spark.memory.fraction <- 0.9
```

I get the following error:

> Blockquote
>     Error in value[3L] : 
>       Failed to fetch data: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due 
>       to stage failure: Task 10 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent 
>       failure: Lost task 10.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 132, localhost, executor 
>       driver): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/blockmgr-9ded7dfb-20b8-
>       4c72-8a6f-2db12ba884fb/1f/temp_shuffle_e69d56ba-80b4-499f-a91f-
>       0ae63fe4553f (Too many open files)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
>       at java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:213)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.initialize(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:102)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:115)
>       at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:235)
>       at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:152)
>       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMa

I increased ulimit to 419430 from 1040 (both soft and hard) and this made no difference.

My VM has 128 cores and 2T of memory and I'd like to be able to use all of it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Spark `local` mode is intended for low-volume experimentation and unit testing, not for production usage and problems with system limits are just a peak of the iceberg. It operates in a single JVM and you may expect a lot of different issues just with memory management.

Overall Spark is designed for scaling out not for scaling up. You shouldn't expect performance gains and painless operation when increasing resources in local mode. Moreover, if computational resources are not backed with high throughput disk configuration your resources will be underutilized.